# Debugging Google Spreadsheet script using libraries

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, google-sheets, ide, libraries

I am applying scripts in Google spreadsheets.
Using the debugger it is easy to to find errors in the script that is local to the spreadsheet (container). In the script I use functions of external libraries, which is running fine.
However, when using the debugger I am not able anymore to enter the library script. The debugger works fine as long as the script is local. But as soon as an external function is called I get an error

> Cannot connect to server

when entering the code.
Using the execute command from within the debugger works fine.
Question
In the past I was able to use the debugging function also to debug library functions. Somehow this has changed.
Does anyone know what the reason is?

Comment: Only Google can tell the reason but maybe they will never share that publicly. Why do you need to know it ? Knowing this, what problem you might solve?

Comment: It's been some time since this was reported and no updates were given. I won't expect this to be fixed within the year as the priority is not bumped to P1. Hopefully google can be more transparent with the issues filed but I guess that would be near impossible due to the high number of issues they get regularly.

Answer (score 1):

As per checking, it seems this is a well-known bug. Check [Cannot debug library, debugger does not step in](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167903155) for details and bump the issue if you can.

<strike>You might also want to try and check if you can do it via the old IDE.</strike>

#### EDIT:

As per Rubén, seems like it also doesn't work on the old IDE too.

#### References:

- [Debugging Library Code (New IDE)](https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/0tPq4HMF7S0?pli=1)

Comment: It doesn't work either on the old IDE

Comment: @Rubén, that's unfortunate. Hope this gets fixed soon.